# Base64 decode fails with "No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page."

Tags: delphi, base64, azure-table-storage

I am trying to create the signature string needed for Azure Storage Tables as described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key#encoding-the-signature

The Access key is `"p1qPD2lBiMlDtl/Vb/T/Xt5ysd/ZXNg5AGrwJvtrUbyqiAQxGabWkR9NmKWb8Jhd6ZIyBd9HA3kCRHr6eveKaA=="`

The failing code is:

```pascal
property AccessKey: string read FAccessKey write SetAccessKey;

function TAzureStorageAPI.GetAuthHeader(StringToSign: UTF8String): UTF8String;
var
  AccessKey64: string;
begin
  AccessKey64 := URLEncoding.Base64.Decode(AccessKey);
  Result := URLEncoding.Base64.Encode(CalculateHMACSHA256(StringtoSign,AccessKey64));
end;
```

What can I do to get this working?

I have checked that `AccessKey` decodes on https://www.base64decode.org/ and it converts to strange data, but it is what I am supposed to do.... :-/

Comment: Use `.DecodeStringToBytes()` and assign the result to `TBytes` instead of `String`. Decoding anything is not automatically becoming text.

Comment: `Base64.Decode(string)` decodes the base64 to bytes, and then decodes the bytes as UTF-8 into a `string`. In this case, the decoded bytes are not UTF-8 data, hence the error. You don't want a decoded string anyway, you need the original bytes instead. HMAC operates on bytes.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `CalculateHMACSHA256()` comes from [blindly copying it](https://www.delphipraxis.net/1451605-post1.html) and just fiddling everything to make the compiler happy. But there are still logical flaws all over. Without testing I'd write it this way:

```
function GetAuthHeader
( StringToSign: UTF8String  // Expecting an UTF-8 encoded text
; AzureAccountKey: String  // Base64 is ASCII, so text encoding is almost irrelevant
): String;  // Result is ASCII, too, not UTF-8
var
  HMAC: TIdHMACSHA256;
begin
  HMAC:= TIdHMACSHA256.Create;
  try
    // Your key must be treated as pure binary - don't confuse it with
    // a human-readable text-like password. This corresponds to the part
    // "Base64.decode(<your_azure_storage_account_shared_key>)"
    HMAC.Key:= URLEncoding.Base64.DecodeStringToBytes( AzureAccessKey );

    result:= URLEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString  // The part "Signature=Base64(...)"
    ( HMAC.HashValue  // The part "HMAC-SHA256(...,...)"
      ( IndyTextEncoding_UTF8.GetBytes( StringToSign )  // The part "UTF8(StringToSign)"
      )
    );
  finally
    HMAC.Free;
  end;
end;
```

No guarantee as I have no chance to compile it myself.

Using `ToHex()` anywhere makes no sense if you encode it all in [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) anyway. And stuffing everything into `UTF8String` makes no sense either then. Hashing always implies working with bytes, not text - never mix up binary with `String`.