# Azure Storage Table Access

Tags: delphi, azure-table-storage

I am trying to implement Azure Storage Table access in Delphi based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key#table-service-shared-key-authorization

If use the SharedKey from Azure-Portal in the call.
But I always get a 400 error from the REST call.

the code is

```
  function CalculateHMACSHA256(const Value, salt:string):string;
    var
      hmac: TIdHMACSHA256;
      Hash: TIdBytes;
    begin
      LoadOpenSSLLibrary;
      if not TIdHashSHA256.IsAvailable then
        raise Exception.Create('SHA256 hashing is not available!');
      hmac:=TIdHMACSHA256.Create;
      try
        hmac.Key:=IndyTextEncoding_UTF8.GetBytes(salt);
        Hash:=hmac.HashValue(IndyTextEncoding_UTF8.GetBytes(Value));
        result:=ToHex(Hash);
      finally
        hmac.Free;
      end;
    end;

  function TAzureStorageAPI.Canonicalize(URI:string):string;
    begin
      result:='/'+StorageAccount+'/'+URI;
    end;

  function TAzureStorageAPI.GetAuthHeader(RequestMethod, Ressource, Time: UTF8String): UTF8String;
    var
      AccessKey64:string;
      ContentMD5, ContentType, Date, Content, Separator: UTF8String;
      StringtoSign: UTF8String;
    begin
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key#table-service-shared-key-authorization
      ContentType:='application/json; charset=UTF-8';
      Separator:=LF;
      StringtoSign:=Uppercase(RequestMethod)+Separator+// RequestMethod
       ContentMD5+Separator+// contentMD5
       ContentType+Separator+// contentType
       Date+Separator+// requestDate
       Canonicalize(Ressource); // Ressource
      result:=URLEncoding.base64.Encode(CalculateHMACSHA256(StringtoSign,AccessKey));
    end;

  function TAzureStorageAPI.Insert(PartitionKey, RowKey:string; Data: tJSONObject): TWebAPIJSONResponse;
    var
      PostHeaders: TStringlist;
      Time: TDateTime;
      URI, TimeString:string;
    begin
      URI:='https://'+StorageAccount+'.table.core.windows.net/'+Table+'';
      Time:=TTimeZone.Local.ToUniversalTime(Now);
      TimeString:=FormatDateTime('ddd, dd mmm yyyy hh:nn:ss "GMT"', Time);
      PostHeaders:=TStringlist.Create;
      PostHeaders.Add('x-ms-version:2019-07-07');
      PostHeaders.Add('Date:'+TimeString);
      PostHeaders.Add('x-ms-date:'+TimeString);
      PostHeaders.Add('MaxDataServiceVersion:3.0;NetFx');
      PostHeaders.Add('DataServiceVersion:3.0;NetFx');
      PostHeaders.Add('Authorization:SharedKey '+StorageAccount+':'+GetAuthHeader('POST', URI, TimeString));
      Host:=StorageAccount+'.table.core.windows.net';
      Data.AddPair('PartitionKey', PartitionKey);
      Data.AddPair('RowKey', RowKey);
      result:=WebPostData('/'+Table, PostHeaders, Data);
      FreeAndNIL(PostHeaders);
    end;
```

Any help would be very appriciated. I have tried using '\n' as a separator, variuos variations of Base64, UTF8 and HMASHA256 encodings. Nothing works :-/

Comment: (You have forgotten the `try..finally` block protecting the `PostHeaders` `TStringList`.)

Comment: `GetAuthHeader()` is handled in [a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66080788/4299358) - cut it off from this one! The rest is a mess and I guess everything you tried was without actually understanding even one of all the contexts used here (hashing, HTTP header, JSON, UTF-8, MD5, MIME, HMAC, SHA...) - it's just glued on like a ransom note...

Comment: @Amigo Please consider a less unfriendly way to express your frustration ;)